# Uncertainty product at $t=0$ for a constant equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Given the S.E
$$
\Psi(x,0) = 
\begin{cases} A,&0 \leq x \leq \frac{a}{2}, \\ 0,& \rm elsewhere
\end{cases}
$$
I'm supposed to find the uncertainty product at $t=0$. However since the equation is constant it doesn't seem to satisfy the uncertainty principle.

For the expectation value of $p$ and $p^{2}$ i get
$$
\langle p \rangle = - i \hbar |A|^{2}d
\int_{0}^{\frac{a}{2}}\frac{d}{dx}  dx = 0 
$$
and the same for $\langle p^{2} \rangle$ which result in the uncertainty  $\Delta p = 0$. But this isn't allowed according to the uncertainty principle.
Where is the catch?

Comment: The wavefunction is not differentiable. Somewhat similar situation: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221027/2451

Comment: What do you mean by S.E.? If you mean "Schrödinger Equation", then that's definitely *not* applicable to the wavefunction example you give at the start of your post.

Answer (score 2):

Your wavefunction is not differentiable. If you want to calculate its momentum uncertainty, you need to look at your state in the momentum representation,
\begin{align}
\tilde\Psi(p)
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Psi(x) e^{-ipx/\hbar} \mathrm dx
\\ & = \frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \int_0^{a/2} e^{-ipx/\hbar} \mathrm dx
%\\ & = \frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \frac{e^{-ipa/2\hbar}-1}{p/\hbar}
%\\ & = \frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \frac{e^{-ipa/4\hbar}-e^{-ipa/4\hbar}}{p/\hbar}e^{-ipa/4\hbar}
%\\ & = \frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \frac{-2i\sin(pa/4\hbar)}{p/\hbar}e^{-ipa/4\hbar}
\\ & = \frac{Aa}{2i\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \frac{\sin(pa/4\hbar)}{pa/4\hbar}e^{-ipa/4\hbar}
\\ & = \frac{Aa}{2i\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \mathrm{sinc}(pa/4\hbar)e^{-ipa/4\hbar}.
\end{align}
(Intermediate steps commented in [this answer's source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/397864/edit/17cec074-528b-46e9-9fba-8598b2d74119).) Your task is then to calculate the variance of the momentum directly in the momentum representation,
$$
\langle p^2\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\tilde \Psi(p)|^2 p^2 \,\mathrm dp,
$$
using the above wavefunction. You should be able to easily verify that the momentum variance is infinite, which corresponds to the fact that the position-representation wavefunction is neither continuous nor differentiable and it thus, strictly speaking, falls outside of the domain of the momentum operator.