# Property of a wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, complex-numbers

We know that a wavefunction can't be completely real, because then it would have some complex expectation values for some operators. If we let $\psi$ be a real wavefunction, then
$$\langle P\rangle= \int{\psi^*\left(-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) \psi\, dx}$$
would be imaginary, which is not allowed.

Just like this, can a wavefunction be completely imaginary?

I think it won't be possible, because then the $i$ will cancel out, and the expectation will be again imaginary.  Am I right or wrong?
And I also want to know *why* an operator can't have imaginary expectation value?

Comment: Related: [Can the momentum operator have an imaginary expectation value?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221027/2451)

Comment: What you have shown is that if $\psi(x)$ is real then $\langle p\rangle$ must be $0$.  This does not imply that $\psi$ must be complex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only constraint on a particle's wavefunction $\psi$ is that it must be square-integrable - i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \overline{\psi(x)} \psi(x) \mathrm dx < \infty$.  So it's perfectly possible to have an entirely $\mathbb R$-valued wavefunction, or an entirely imaginary ($i\mathbb R$-valued) wavefunction, or neither.  Additionally, given an arbitrary operator $\mathcal O$, the expected value
$$\langle\mathcal O\rangle_\psi = \langle \psi,\mathcal O\psi\rangle$$
is generally $\mathbb C$-valued and need not belong to $\mathbb R$.

**However** if $\mathcal O$ happens to be self-adjoint so that $\mathcal O^\dagger = \mathcal O$, it's easy to see that the expected value must be real:
$$\langle \mathcal O\rangle_\psi = \langle \psi,\mathcal O\psi\rangle = \langle \mathcal O\psi,\psi\rangle = \overline{\langle \psi,\mathcal O \psi\rangle} = \overline{\langle \mathcal O\rangle_\psi}$$

where the line denotes complex conjugation and we've used the fact that for self-adjoint operators, $\langle \psi,\mathcal O\phi\rangle = \langle\mathcal O\psi,\phi\rangle$.

---

For your example of the momentum operator for a particle on a line $P = -i \frac{d}{dx}$ and a wavefunction $\psi$ which is $\mathbb R$-valued, we have
$$\langle P\rangle_\psi = -i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \overline{\psi(x)}\psi'(x) \mathrm dx $$
which is $i$ multiplied by a manifestly real number. However, we are saved by the fact that if $\psi$ is real then $\overline{\psi(x)}=\psi(x)$ and so we have

$$\langle P\rangle_\psi = -i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \overline{\psi(x)}\psi'(x) \mathrm dx  = -i \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}\big(\psi(x)\big)^2 \mathrm dx = -\frac{i}{2} \big[\psi(\infty)^2 -\psi(-\infty)^2\big]$$
$$ = 0$$
Therefore, if $\psi$ is purely real then $\langle P\rangle_\psi=0$.

Comment: Ok I understood it . Let me explain it .... As you told the expectation value in general need not to be mandatorily real or complex . But if operator is hermitian or self adjoint then expectation must be real valued . And as in general all the operators used to define physical quantities are hermitian , so we generally encounter real expectation values .

Comment: @MSagnik. Yes, measurable quantities are represented by self-adjoint operators, so their expectation values must be real.  There are certainly operators which are of interest which are *not* self-adjoint (e.g. unitary operators, which represent symmetry transformations), but they simply don't represent observables.

Comment: I've always been taught that physical quantities are represented by hermitian operators *precisely* because physical quantities are expected to be real-valued.

Comment: @ZachMcDargh That's usually the motivation, yes. However, it's worth noting that physical quantities should be represented by operators which are *diagonalizable* as well as having $\mathbb R$-valued spectra, with the latter also being guaranteed by self-adjointness. In other words, the former is not the *only* requirement which motivates self-adjointness because it's possible to have a non-self-adjoint operator which has real eigenvalues but is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

If $\psi(x)$ is a "completely real" wavefunction, then $\phi(x) \equiv i \psi(x)$ is an "completely imaginary" wavefunction that is experimentally indistinguishable from $\psi(x)$.  This is because multiplying a wavefunction by an overall phase of $i = e^{i \pi/2}$ does not change the results of any experiment.  So any statement you can make about expectation values of "completely real" wavefunctions can be made about "completely imaginary" wavefunctions as well.